# Can it be plagiarism if one uses another author's phrase?

Tags: plagiarism

I was considering using the simile "like a sailor cast on a desert rock" (used first by Wordsworth), but was uncertain whether its mention without reference in a short story would be plagiarism.

Context: "He was drowning helplessly like a sailor cast on a desert rock."

Comment: Would it be part of dialog? Is it part of your narrative? A description?  Please show how you would use it by giving a complete sentence that contains the phrase.

Comment: I think you could probably get by (and generate some google searches as well as some respect for your knowledge of Wordsworth to boot) by simply using: "like Wordsworth's sailor cast on a desert rock."

Comment: @PapaPoule I would write that but it just doesn't appear appropriate in the context/

Comment: Is your intention to allude to Wordsworth, as a nod to readers who might be familiar with the phrase, or to just steal the simile?

Comment: I suggested that just as you were editing to add the context, but whether it's "a" sailor or "Wordsworth's" sailor, would a simile about being on a desert rock be appropriate for someone downing helplessly? Seems like someone in that predicament would love to find himself on any rock, no?

Comment: @PapaPoule Yes, I acknowledge that, but the addition of a context was only to hint that it is in a short story that I am using this simile and thus have no desire to make any formal references to other writers.

Comment: @amt528 My intention is to "steal the simile" if you will.

Comment: Anyway, it's a cool simile, thanks for sharing it. Just be sure to leave instructions with the administrators of your estate not to pursue anyone who "steals" it from your work in the future and you should be fine!!

Comment: It's entirely up to you, of course, but be sure to consider giving upvotes to any and all answers that you found helpful.

Comment: One more comment: I'm not sure this simile is very powerful, because it relates too closely to actually drowning.  I think the best similes compare really dissimilar things, like: "Top-heavy was the ship as a dinnerless student with all Aristotle in his head."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it is [plagiarism](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plagiarism) since you are aware of using a specific known sentence/verse by a famous author as if it was your own in a formal work:

> - the unauthorized use of the language and thoughts of another author and the representation of them as one's own.
> - An instance of plagiarizing, especially a passage that is taken from the work of one person and reproduced in the work of another without attribution.

The Free Dictionary

Comment: I trust you realise that Wordsworth is no longer around to "authorize" the use of his phrase.

Comment: @fdb - that doesn't mean that it would not be plagiarism to use his language, what OP has to do is to cite the source.

Answer (score 0):

If I did it I think I would make it clear, e.g.

> John looked out of the window. Right now, he felt *like a sailor cast on a desert rock*.

I've given a possible context. What is your context?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be plagiarism unless it is such a recurrent reference it has become a symbol everyone recognizes.